# Calculate effects using delta method in R

Tags: r

I have written a code to calculate effects using Delta method in R

I have a dataframe `dpcp` with variables `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4` and a matrix of 1000 draws from a multivariate normal, `m4[1000,4]`.

This code calculates the effects, but it takes very long to run.

How can I run it faster:

```
n = nrow(dpcp)
for (i in 1: n) {
    for (j in 1: 1000) {
        marg_effects[i, j] = (m4[j, 1] * dpcp[i, ] $x1) + (m4[j, 2] * dpcp[i, ] $x2)+ (m4[j, 3] * dpcp[i, ] $x3) + (m4[j, 4] * dpcp[i, ] $x4)
    }
}
```

The code currently takes upwards of 5 hours for even 2000 observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122066/how-to-use-delta-method-for-standard-errors-of-marginal-effects) out first. However, to speed up your computation, just use matrix multiplication instead of looping

```
marg_effects <- as.matrix(dpcp) %*% t(m4)
```

The `%*%` operator is for matrix multiplication and the `t()` function is to transpose `m4`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it was very useful in speeding the code up. I checked out the link, it involves calculating effects at the average level while the code above was for calculating them at the individual observation level.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your code is running slowly is because you haven't pre-specified the `marg_effects[i, j]` matrix. Therefore, each run has to add a new row to the matrix which is very computationally efficient. Defining the matrix first should lead to faster run times:

```
n = nrow(dpcp)
marg_effects <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 1000)
for (i in 1: n) {
    for (j in 1: 1000) {
        marg_effects[i, j] = (m4[j, 1] * dpcp[i, ] $x1) + (m4[j, 2] * dpcp[i, ] $x2)+ (m4[j, 3] * dpcp[i, ] $x3) + (m4[j, 4] * dpcp[i, ] $x4)
    }
}
```